# Facebook iFrame app, is this code correct?

Tags: php, facebook

I've just thrown together a quick Facebook iFrame "fangate" app, where you must "like" to reveal a page.

I've seen a number of ways of doing things online so I just wanted to check that my method was safe to use before I publish the app.

..and the code..:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => "__CODE_HERE__",
'secret' => "__CODE_HERE__",
'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    if($signed_request != false){
        if($signed_request["page"]["liked"]) {
          echo "you LIKE this page now!!";
        } else {
          // User likes the fan page.. display restricted data.
          include 'index.php';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('LOCATION: http://www.facebook.com/');
    }

  ?>
```

What do you guys think? This seems pretty secure and the is the most common method i've come across. Would you include anything else?

All feedback welcome.. :)

--Conor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't load the whole PHP-SDK *only* for this, instead I use the approach from the documentation:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
    echo "You are not a fan!";
} else {
    echo "Welcome back fan!";
}
```

I've written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) about this and provided a real world examples of the importance of this.

Comment: Hi ifaour,
I had seen this solution somewhere but the author said it was "cheating" and not secure.

I see you have a check in your function which is good.

I will go with that.. Thanks.

Comment: @Conor H: what about the "cheating" part?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problem with this. I have seen similar solutions working like this.